# C++ equivalent to Java ArrayList method removeAll

Tags: java, c++, vector, arraylist

The Java `ArrayList` `removeAll()` method takes a collection as an argument and removes this collection from the `ArrayList` that calls the method. How would an equivalent action be accomplished on a `vector` in c++?

Comment: Please use a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), where the interface is clearly documented.

Comment: Actually, `std::vector::clear` is not the equivalent. `std::vector::clear` erases everything unconditionally, while `ArrayList.removeAll(c)` removes things conditionally.

Comment: As Nicky C said, clear does not do what I want. I have searched the reference sites and have not found an equivalent function, at least not within std::vector.

Comment: I have a question though. Does Java `ArrayList.removeAll(c)` removes entries when the *objects* are compared equal, or removes entries when the *references* are compared equal?

Comment: @NickyC The contract of Java `Collection.removeAll(Collection c)` (`ArrayList implements List extends Collection`) is to use `Object.equals()` for comparison. So, the *objects* are compared equal, not the *references* (except for `null`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such method in `std::vector`.

The design philosophy of the Standard Library is that we don't implement everything inside the class. Instead, there is a plenty of algorithms that operates on the containers.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm

Unfortunately, there is no equivalent among the standard algorithms too. But you can write an algorithm basing on them.

```
#include <algorithm>

template <class Container, class RemoveTargetContainer>
typename Container::iterator remove_for(Container& container, const RemoveTargetContainer& targets)
{
    auto container_first = std::begin(container);
    auto container_last = std::end(container);

    std::for_each(std::begin(targets), std::end(targets),
        [&](typename RemoveTargetContainer::const_reference target)
        {
            container_last = std::remove(container_first, container_last, target);
        }
    );

    return container_last;
}
```

This is the usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myContainer { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
    std::deque<int> removalTargets { 1,3,5,7 };

    myContainer.erase(remove_for(myContainer, removalTargets), std::end(myContainer));

    for (const auto& x : myContainer)
        std::cout << x << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

PS: I don't like the name `removeAll`. It is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution:

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// Remove all in c2 from c1
template<typename Collection1, typename Collection2>
void removeAll(Collection1& c1, const Collection2& c2)
{
    for(auto&& i: c2)
        c1.erase(std::remove_if(c1.begin(), c1.end(), [i](decltype(i) i1){return i == i1;}), c1.end());
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 {1, 5, 3, 6, 4, 6, 2, 6, 7};
    std::set<int> v2 {5, 6, 2};

    removeAll(v1, v2);

    // display results
    for(auto&& i: v1)
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
3
4
7
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no doubt the above answers are effective solutions, I just can't get them to compile. I'm a C++ beginner and haven't studied generic usage yet, but the compiler complained about the square brackets ([]) in each solution. I ended up writing my own solution. I'm sure it will make c++ vets cringe, but it appears to work. Here it is.

```
#include <vector>

void removeAll(std::vector<int>& original, const std::vector<int>& partition1){ 
for (int i=0; i<original.size();i++) {
    for (int x: partition1) {
        if (x == original[i]){
           original.erase(original.begin() + i);
           --i;
           break;
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: The "square brackets" thing in our answers is called "lambda function", which is newly introduced to the language in 2011 (the "C++11" ISO Standard) (not quite new actually, as the latest is C++14 now). You are not able to use it probably because your compiler is too old, or your compiler does not make C++11 support as the default setting.

Comment: Also note that all these answers are quadratic, which means that they are great for small arrays, but if you try to remove hundred thousand elements from one million elements vector, they will take minutes or hours. While my answer below was not well received by this community, it offers an approach that will finish in under a second for the same constraints

Comment: I don't think I mentioned it in my question, but I require duplicate elements in the collections I'm using, which I don't believe set allows.

Comment: So is [2,2,2].removeAll([2,2]) is [2], or []? If the latter, as your final solution suggests, then my answer still works, even though it converts the vector to the set. Note that the input is still a vector, and since for every element in the second vector we remove all occurrences of it from the first vector, it doesn't matter if we dedup it before starting removing elements or not.

Answer (score -1):

There's no such method in C++ for `std::vector`. One way to do that, that has very good runtime, unlike other suggested implementations, is to convert the second collection into a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`, and iterate over the first vector, keeping only the elements that do not belong to the set, something along the lines of:

```cpp
template <class T>
void removeAll(std::vector<T>& in, const std::vector<T>& removeWhat) {
    std::set<T> st(removeWhat.begin(), removeWhat.end());
    size_t newSize = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < in.size(); ++ i) {
        if (0 == st.count(in[i])) {
            in[newSize ++] = in[i];
        }
    }
    in.resize(newSize);
}
```

But this only works if your `T` has an operator `<` overloaded (requirement of `std::set`). It is for ints, so it will work in your particular case.